# Place list item text link in circle

Tags: css, html

I want to style nav links fixed next to the scroll bar. These links should be in a circle and stacked vertically down the scroll bar. I was able to get the desired effect using li styling, but it is not HTML5 Semantic.

Here is the jsFiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/heez31k3/2/)

The first nav class is working but is not correct HTML5 semantic. When I correct it, it no longer displays! (You will need to remove the comment tags to see the difference, sorry I didn't know how to run multiple at once)

How can I move my `li a` styling correctly into the `ul`?

For those who would prefer, here is the code directly instead of jsFiddle:

**CSS:**

```
/*move the step dots to the far right*/
.stepDots{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:40%;
  width:40px;
  height:150px;
  display: table;
}

/*align/style the text inside a circle*/
.stepDots li{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin:25px auto;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color:#fff;
  border-radius:100px;
  transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

/*react to hover-over steps*/
.stepDots li:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  color:#000;
}

/*remove default navigation decoration underline*/
.stepDots a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<!--Example of desired effect, but NOT valid-->
<nav class="stepDots">
  <a title="1" href="javascript:showStep('1');"><li>1</li></a>
  <a title="2" href="javascript:showStep('2');"><li>2</li></a>
  <a title="3" href="javascript:showStep('3');"><li>3</li></a>
  <a title="4" href="javascript:showStep('4');"><li>4</li></a>
  <a title="5" href="javascript:showStep('5');"><li>5</li></a>
  <a title="6" href="javascript:showStep('6');"><li>6</li></a>
</nav>

<!--NOT working but valid -->
<!--
<nav class="stepDots">
  <ul>
    <li><a title="1" href="javascript:showStep('1');">1</a></li>
    <li><a title="2" href="javascript:showStep('2');">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="3" href="javascript:showStep('3');">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="4" href="javascript:showStep('4');">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="5" href="javascript:showStep('5');">5</a></li>
    <li><a title="6" href="javascript:showStep('6');">6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
-->

<!--this is also NOT valid and NOT working (but closer to expected) -->
<!--
<nav class="stepDots">
  <li><a title="1" href="javascript:showStep('1');">1</a></li>
  <li><a title="2" href="javascript:showStep('2');">2</a></li>
  <li><a title="3" href="javascript:showStep('3');">3</a></li>
  <li><a title="4" href="javascript:showStep('4');">4</a></li>
  <li><a title="5" href="javascript:showStep('5');">5</a></li>
  <li><a title="6" href="javascript:showStep('6');">6</a></li>
</nav> 
-->
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to Gaurang Dave's answer below I made some changes to get the results I was after.

Future reference Jsfiddle link [here](https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/nvrort1v/) or code:

```
.stepDots{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:40%;
  display: block;
}

/*remove list item bullet points*/
.stepDots li{
  list-style-type: none;
}

/*align/style the text inside a circle*/
.stepDots li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  margin:5px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color: #fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
  line-height: 30px;
}

.stepDots li:hover a {
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
}

<nav> <!--Style step links into navigation bubbles on the right-->
  <ul class="stepDots">
    <li><a title="1" href="javascript:showStep('1');">1</a></li>
    <li><a title="2" href="javascript:showStep('2');">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="3" href="javascript:showStep('3');">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="4" href="javascript:showStep('4');">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="5" href="javascript:showStep('5');">5</a></li>
    <li><a title="6" href="javascript:showStep('6');">6</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav> <!--end right side navigation-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to edit you code to achieve the result. It will help you to get what you want. You can further modify it.

Try this.

```
<nav>
  <ul class="stepDots">
    <li><a title="1" href="javascript:showStep('1');">1</a></li>
    <li><a title="2" href="javascript:showStep('2');">2</a></li>
    <li><a title="3" href="javascript:showStep('3');">3</a></li>
    <li><a title="4" href="javascript:showStep('4');">4</a></li>
    <li><a title="5" href="javascript:showStep('5');">5</a></li>
    <li><a title="6" href="javascript:showStep('6');">6</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>


/*move the step dots to the far right*/
.stepDots{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:40%;
  display: table;
}

/*align/style the text inside a circle*/
.stepDots li{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  margin:25px auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color:#fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

/*react to hover-over steps*/
.stepDots li:hover{
  background-color:rgba(255,255,255,1);
  color:#000;
}

/*remove default navigation decoration underline*/
.stepDots a{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**UPDATE-1**

Replace following two classes in your current css.

```
/*move the step dots to the far right*/
.stepDots{
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
  top:40%;
  display: block;
}

/*align/style the text inside a circle*/
.stepDots li{
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: block;
  margin:5px auto;
  text-align:center;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  color:#fff;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  transition:all 200ms ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Gaurang Dave your solution is really good, I was looking to have the numbers under each-other, but in yours they run horizontally. I have been trying to alter your answer by modifying the table display but no luck. Still very new to css, here is what your edit looks like live: https://jsfiddle.net/peggory/713gr8oo/18/ Is it possible to edit yours to run vertically against the scroll bar rather than horizontally? Thanks

Comment: Check UPDATE-1 in my answer. You can change margin and text alignment as per you need.